# Get current element in listview

Tags: chat, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing a simple messenger. I want to implement message seen/unseen feature. How can i get the position of the marked elements, these elements are inside the wrap layout which is inside the listview?

[image]

This is the code i am using to render messages.

```
<ListView (loaded)="testLoad($event)"
   #chatBox
   separatorColor="transparent"
   class="chat-box"
   [items]="messages"
  (loaded)="scrollChatToBottom()"
  row="0">
  <ng-template let-item="item">
  <StackLayout 
    class="bubble-container">
    <Label
        [text]="item.createdAt | timeAgo"
        class="message-date-{{bubbleClass(item)}} SourceSansPro- 
   LightItalic"></Label>
    <WrapLayout 
      [class]="bubbleClass(item)" orientation="horizontal">
      <!--<Image 
      [src]="item.sender.pictureUrl"
      [class]="bubbleClass(item) + '-picture'">e></Imag-->
      <TextView
        editable="false"
        class="message-content SourceSansPro-Regular"
        [text]="item.messageBody"></TextView> 

    </WrapLayout >

    </StackLayout>
   </ng-template>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of ListView is to reuse the View (template) as needed, only the data may be different but the same instance of View will be reused for different indexes as you scroll.

So in general you should control your View by your data. If you are planning to show read message as bold / light or in different color it can be done via CSS, so  just have to bind the right class based on read / unread flag in your data item.

If you still want to access the actual View element, it may be possible with [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radlistview#getviewforitem). I don't think there is an easy way to access the View instance in ListView at the moment.

Comment: actually i want to implement message read feature.. on scroll only visible messages on viewport  will be read. My idea is to send visible messages id to backend...

Comment: In that case you could use `itemLoading` event I guess, notified every time when View has to be created for data at index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ListView, but I supouse always can use a directive to get the ElementRef. If you has the ElementRef you can get the el.nativeElement.offsetTop.

So, the only thing it's make some like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pos]'
})
export class PosDirective  {
  @Input('pos') index:number;
  el:ElementRef
  constructor(el:ElementRef){ 
    this.el=el;
   }
}
```

Our directive need the "index". I put a simple example using a ngFor in `<p>`

```
<p [pos]="i" *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index">{{item}}</p>
<button (click)="showPos(0)">click</button>
```

We "get the p" (really the directive) using ViewChildren

```
  @ViewChildren(PosDirective)positions:QueryList<PosDirective>;

  showPos(index:number)
  {
    const elem=(this.positions.toArray()[index]) as PosDirective;
    console.log(elem.el.nativeElement.offsetTop)
  }
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jqpma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)